# call 2 bound field on gridview in same column

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am trying to call 2 Data field in same column, it that possible to do so? my date is replace my user name

```
BoundField userNameBF = new BoundField();
userNameBF.HeaderText = "User Name";
userNameBF.DataField = "userName";
userNameBF.DataField = "PostDate";
userNameBF.ItemStyle.Width = 180;
GridView2.Columns.Add(userNameBF);
```

**Output**

```
+---------------+
| user Name     |
+---------------+
|               |
| 22/02/2012    |
+---------------+
|               |
| 22/02/2012    |
+---------------+
```

**Expected Output**

```
+---------------+
| user Name     |
+---------------+
| Ken           |
| 22/02/2012    |
+---------------+
| Ryu           |
| 22/02/2012    |
+---------------+
```

Comment: You'd have an easier time if you used an <ItemTemplate> in the <GridView> unless the fields your binding are arbitrary.

Comment: Eric H are u mind to give me sample ? i am not really sure how to call ItemTemplate through code behind

Answer (score 0):

With ASP.NET there tends to be a multitude of routes you can take; although Eric H pretty much nails it using an ItemTemplate to add some basic formatting, i.e.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" Runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SomeField"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AnotherField"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("userName") %><br /><%# Eval("PostDate") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

although alternatives do exist such as joining the fields together using a DataView / LINQ inserting the 
 tag and then simply binding that field.